# NiFi make single Database call after processing multiple flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a below scenario, I am trying

1. get new files list with ListFile processor
2. set a constant variable  zipFilesBundleConstant = listBundle on each flowfile
3. Put the list to Database
4. Get all the list of files old and new from Database to process further with ExecuteSQL processor. (Here I want to make only one Database call to fetch complete list old and new, but ExecuteSQL is being called for all the flowfiles)

I tried keeping MergeContent processor with zipFilesBundleConstant as Correlation Attribute Name before ExecuteSQL to combine all the flowfiles but that is not working as expected and it merges some but always gives me multiple flowfiles.

Can anyone please help me with a solution on how to make a one call after inserting the new files list into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExecuteSQL processor has separate workflow to fetch existing old files list from the database with the scheduling strategy as per the requirement.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab

Comment: No, it should be a single and continuous flow, as I have to keep track of other variables